# Why is my spring batch app not processing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I've been trying my hardest to make a simple spring batch app that reads a CSV and prints results out to the log. I cannot get this thing to work. I would really appreciate any info on what I've done wrong.

I've made a github repo : https://github.com/rtconner/hello

I am expecting to see the `Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")` line from the processor. Also I expect to see the log line from the `LogItemWriter` printed to the log. I never see either of those printed out.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Add the code to illustrate the problem to the question instead. Also add any errors/problems description. The `not processing` means nothing.

Comment: If I knew what the problem was, I would totally add that code. I do not know what is causing the problem at all.

Comment: Then you need to take some time and create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  A lot of the time, the work involved in paring an app down to a failing example will isolate the problem enough that you'll solve it yourself, incidentally.

Comment: I tried very hard to do exactly that. This app is as simple as I could make it.

Comment: ..please run the gradle(?) build with `--stacktrace --debug` options/arguments, and share with us some (relevant) output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making multiple mistakes in your project.

**Root Cause :**

In your `Àpplication.java`  , you are passing your configuration class where as there it needs to be your `Application.class` itself.

`SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` instead of `SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args);`

Once you fix this - you are going to face multiple other errors that are wrong in your project,

1. **No Spring batch repository is set** : Every Spring batch project needs a job repository to run and that is not configured in your project. If you don't want to use a persistent db , you can go with in memory db with these ,

add dependency , `compile 'com.h2database:h2'` and below Java configuration,

```
@Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(ResourcelessTransactionManager txManager)
            throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(txManager);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }
```

I have not tried it but if H2 or HSQLDB is present in your classpath, probably, you wouldn't need above configuration. I added for the sake of completeness.

2. **Incorrect hibernate validator dependency** : This below dependency is not hibernate validator but hibernate core ,

`compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'`  while what you need is ,

`compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.2.1.Final'`

I ran your application after fixing these things and below are logs ,

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-07-02 15:02:15.966  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on Bi-amma with PID 4872 (E:\GithubSamples\hello-master\bin started by kaneez in E:\GithubSamples\hello-master)
2017-07-02 15:02:15.971  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-02 15:02:16.114  INFO 4872 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45dd4eda: startup date [Sun Jul 02 15:02:16 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-02 15:02:16.786  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=batchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [hello/BatchConfiguration.class]]
2017-07-02 15:02:16.788  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jobRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=batchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [hello/BatchConfiguration.class]]
2017-07-02 15:02:16.788  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jobLauncher' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobLauncher; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=batchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobLauncher; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [hello/BatchConfiguration.class]]
2017-07-02 15:02:17.273  WARN 4872 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-07-02 15:02:17.301  WARN 4872 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-07-02 15:02:17.922  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2017-07-02 15:02:17.994  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.BatchConfiguration                 : Build Job
2017-07-02 15:02:17.996  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.BatchConfiguration                 : Build Step
2017-07-02 15:02:18.727  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql]
2017-07-02 15:02:18.826  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql] in 98 ms.
2017-07-02 15:02:19.130  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-07-02 15:02:19.153  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2017-07-02 15:02:19.164  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2017-07-02 15:02:19.346  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2017-07-02 15:02:19.447  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2017-07-02 15:02:19.508  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
Converting (firstName: Jill, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.557  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Jill, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.558  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.LogItemWriter                      : [firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE]
Converting (firstName: Joe, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.565  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Joe, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.565  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.LogItemWriter                      : [firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE]
Converting (firstName: Justin, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.573  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Justin, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.573  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.LogItemWriter                      : [firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE]
Converting (firstName: Jane, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.579  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Jane, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.579  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.LogItemWriter                      : [firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE]
Converting (firstName: John, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.586  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: John, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.588  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.LogItemWriter                      : [firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE]
2017-07-02 15:02:19.625  INFO 4872 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2017-07-02 15:02:19.653  INFO 4872 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 4.332 seconds (JVM running for 6.183)
2017-07-02 15:02:19.658  INFO 4872 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45dd4eda: startup date [Sun Jul 02 15:02:16 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-02 15:02:19.665  INFO 4872 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

I had added a sysout in processor so messages might be repeated.